# The debug browser in Visual Studio fails to operate when a breakpoint is set

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Win 11 machine

Since last week, Google Chrome has not been working when I set a breakpoint in my code. I changed the browser from Chrome to Edge, which seemed to be working until today. But now Edge is giving me the same issue.

I am not sure what caused this issue. The website works fine with both browsers in debug or release mode, as long as there are no breakpoints.

However, as soon as I set a breakpoint in the code behind, the browser stops working. It gets stuck in loading mode and doesn't respond to anything." Break points fail the website to load!

Update:I just find out that if I open a new browser manually and type in the URL of the debugging site, the browser works fine and hits the break point,

The issue is that the browser opened by Visual Studio fails.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue! Opening a new browser it's just a partial solution, you can't debug JS on that window.

Comment: It caused by Edge use the same underly tech as chrome. In this situation, you could try another browser.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently monitoring a similar issue, thought I'd add a link to my ongoing Reddit thread on the subject if that's okay:

In summary, I'm seeing my ASP.Net MVC application "stick" loading any page, if there are any breakpoints in the code (including those in compiled, managed C# .cs classes! not just js/ts files!)

My Reddit thread (created 16th March 2023, ongoing...)
[VS 2022 breakpoints break MVC app](https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudio/comments/11sqn90/any_breakpoint_anywhere_breaks_debugging_in/)